# The study of the physical universe

Tags: soft-question

If physics is the study of the physical universe, wouldn't that mean chemistry, biology, neuroscience, zoology, history, economics, sociology, etc, wouldn't they all be subfields of physics? I believe they are. If anyone can convince me otherwise with a good argument, the answer will be accepted.

Comment: [Obligatory](http://xkcd.com/435)

Comment: And @ChrisWhite wins the prize!

Comment: Important vocabulary word (well, phrase): "effective theory". While we are beginning to be able to solve medium complexity chemistry problems in fundamental terms (see computational chemistry AKA computation quantum mechanics applied to more than a couple of atoms) we're still a long way from being able to do what they do and insisting on doing so would be silly beyond an existence proof.

Comment: No because physics isn't a pseudo-science and at least one of the fields you list and certainly some in the etc. *are*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, yes, everything is physics. Here's how:

1. Depending on your proclivities, use string theory, loop quantum gravity, holography, or the Matrix to create the fundamental particles and forces and possibly spacetime.
2. Use quantum chromodynamics (QCD) to get quarks and gluons to form into protons and neutrons.
3. Use more QCD and quantum electrodynamics (QED) to get the protons and neutrons to fuse into larger nuclei, taking care to make sure they're stable against radioactive decay.
4. Use more QED to get bond electrons to nuclei to create atoms.
5. Use more QED to get the outermost electrons to form stable configurations that result in atoms bonding together into molecules and ionic compounds.

You are now ready to do chemistry. From there you can build the small compounds into biologically-significant molecules and cells to do biology, use the cells to build people and do sociology and psychology, use the sociology and psychology to do economics, et cetera, et cetera, et cetera. Then, starting from the Big Bang, you could simulate all of history including star formation, evolution, and World War II. Again, in principle.

In practice, each of the actions in the numbered list is an entire field of physics all to itself. Plus, even if someone bothered to write the equations for simulating human society at the quark/electron level, there isn't a computer on Earth that could actually run the thing. In order to do useful work, you have to take each field of study and ignore most of the underlying workings until you can prove that there is a significant effect. Doctors care about the chemistry of humans. Economists don't.

Then again, calling everything "applied physics" does annoy non-physicists, so I guess there's some use.

---

Footnote: In the xkcd comic [Purity](http://xkcd.com/435/), I disagree with the position of the mathematician. Math and science are not really comparable in the work they do. Physicists study reality while mathematicians study abstractions. There is a lot of back and forth with inspiration and new tools flowing both ways.  But as a physicist, I must protest anyone standing above us.

And thus, a joke:

A biologist, a physicist, and a mathematician are sitting at an outdoor cafe looking at an empty house across the street. They see two people enter the house. A few minutes later, they see three people exit.

The biologist says, "They must have reproduced."

The physicist says, "Must have been a measurement error."

The mathematician says, "If one more person enters the house, it will be empty again."

Answer (score 1):

Physics is broadly defined (in wikipedia, which puts it splendidly) as the general analysis of nature in order to understand how the universe behaves. This definition is not applicable to the other areas you have listed.

Chemistry is defined as the science studying the properties, structure, composition, and interaction of matter distinct from that of physics. It is the closest science to physics; however, the goals, methods, results, and applications in chemistry differ substantially from those in physics. This is like comparing lions and tigers, same genus but different species.

All the other fields vary moreso from physics. Sociology isn't even comparable; it analyzes human society (not nature) in order to understand how societies behave (not the universe).

But in the end, you can believe that they are all physics if you want. Just like I and other will believe they are not physics. Physics refers to a distinct and separate field. If your definition encompasses everything, then might I suggest that your definition of physics is useless and you should switch to the one we all use to distinguish the fields that fall in what we commonly refer to as physics from everything else?

Comment: Then what should be the term to distinguish the study of the physical universe from physics?

Comment: @user107952 We *do* distinguish these things in the usual self-referential way: physics is what physicist do, and physicist do physics.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. The issue is that different sciences operate at very different levels of abstraction. The tools of a high energy particle physicist are in general useless to the problems addressed by a forest ecologist, and more often than not are worse than useless.

Some physicists study fluid dynamics. While quantum effects sometimes are important and need to be addressed, going down to first principles (i.e., using QCD and QED) is not. It's a case of too much information. The physics studied by fluid dynamicists and the physics studied by high energy particle physicists represent different levels of abstraction, and that's just within physics.

Chemistry is a bit more removed from physics, biology further still. The levels of abstraction generally make physics ever less applicable the further removed from physics a science gets.

That said, all abstractions are leaky. fluid dynamicists and chemists need to concern themselves with quantum mechanics, biologists need to concern themselves with chemistry (and even occasionally, with physics).

Comment: Comparing to engineering is not quite valid here. Science studies things and attempts to find out how those things work and make theories that can predict outcomes to certain events. Engineering is not science; it uses the theories and tools from science to address problems, develop solutions, and perform tasks. It is separate from science. Not worse (I'm originally an engineer myself), but different. You're main point is fine, but the message doesn't have as much impact when you compare two fundamentally different professions

Comment: @Jim: I changed that part of my answer to fluid dynamicists, some of whom can be found in physics departments in universities and publish papers in journals such as *Physics of Fluids* and *Phys Rev E*, both published by the American Physics Society.